# What's the source that יונתן בן עוזיאל passed away 26 sivan?

Tags: history, sources-mekorot

> The tomb of ben Uzziel is located in Amuka, Galilee near Safed,
>   Israel. It is customary to visit ben Uzziel's tomb on Rosh Chodesh,
>   the first day of the lunar month, and on 26 Sivan (the day on which he
>   died,

[Here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9F_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%96%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C) and [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9B%22%D7%95_%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9F) it states that his יום פטירתו is the 26 of sivan, I would like to know if there's a solid source for this.

A old man told me he remembers when he was young they used to travel north to someone else's tomb, they wanted to make it more attractive so they figured they might as well go to יונתן בן עוזיאל, and mysteriously it turned into the official יום פטירתו.

Comment: Tag "memorial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual date is unknown.

the date to celebrate 26 sivan was established,
as in the years 1964 they used to travel from Jerusalem to the north, in honor of רבי ישמעאל בן אלישע כהן גדול from the עשרת הרוגי מלכות that his tomb is in (סאג'ור (ساجور and was killed 25 Sivan, as a incentive to make it more attractive they also went to יונתן בן עוזיאל and Meron,

> Sajur is an Druze town in the Galilee region of northern Israel, with
>   an area of 3,000 dunams

The bus drivers didn't want to go to רבי ישמעאל בן אלישע כהן גדול tomb since they had to pass a Arabic neighborhood in order to get there, they refused to go the passengers protested one bus ended up going the others didn't.

since then the memorial of רבי ישמעאל כהן גדול was forgotten and we were left with traveling to יונתן בן עוזיאל,

Comment: Hi yesitsme, do you have any source for this history?

Comment: yes I asked this old man, he is not a author of a book so I can't reference, he's older then the author of מקומות קדושים וקברי צדיקים בגליל, he told me that you can ask anyone that was in Jerusalem those year.

Comment: He also has the history of the של"ה erev rosh chodesh sivan, maybe I should make a wiki of סגולות, people are really confused, ex: _After lighting a candle for forty days l'ilui nishmas R' Menachem mendel Ben Yosef I saw a Yeshua. This is a popular segula and it is recommended to publicize after the Yeshua._ It's a combination of 3 different ענינים

Answer (score 2):

Sefer  מקומות קדושים וקברי צדיקים בגליל says that the actual date is unknown, however the date that is celebrated is 26 Sivan.

> מקובל שיום ההילולה שלו חל ביום כ"ו סיוון, אך כנראה שיום זה הינו רק יום
>   זיכרון משום שיום פטירתו אינו ידוע

Comment: When was this source published? Who authored it?

Comment: Thanks, from whom is it it מקובל? when did it start? Does מקובל mean that's what the travel agents decided, or there's something to it?

Comment: http://www.zadikim.org/%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A7_%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C.html

Comment: [source](http://www.zadikim.org/?catID=52716&siteLang=3) מקובל שיום ההילולה שלו חל ביום כ"ו סיוון, אך כנראה שיום זה הינו רק יום זיכרון משום שיום פטירתו אינו ידוע